# using vb.net and LibTiff to convert large tiff images

Tags: arrays, vb.net, bitmap, tiff, libtiff

I'm using vb.net and LibTiff to convert large Tiff images, the good news is that the sample given on there site works:

https://bitmiracle.github.io/libtiff.net/?topic=html/e4f25423-eede-4ef6-a920-9cb539d056c6.htm

I'm using this to convert large images into images that are just black n white and can be saved a lot easier. However, its actually a bit too efficient in that its removing a bit too much of the detail in my images. I wondered if anybody knew quite where I can adjust this code so that its not removing quite so many pixels/detail. Need somebody who understands the inner workings of this code/how the tiff file format works I reckon.

I've no doubt there is a setting somewhere in this code somewhere that will allow me to save more of the image and not have quite so much lost.

Below is the code I've been working with from the LibTiff site:

:)

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Imports BitMiracle.LibTiff.Classic

Namespace BitMiracle.LibTiff.Samples
Public NotInheritable Class ImageToBitonalTiff
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub 
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Using bmp As New Bitmap("Sample data\rgb.jpg")
            ' convert using WriteEncodedStrip 
            Dim tiffBytes As Byte() = GetTiffImageBytes(bmp, False)
            File.WriteAllBytes("ImageToBitonalTiff.tif", tiffBytes)

            ' make another conversion using WriteScanline
            tiffBytes = GetTiffImageBytes(bmp, True)
            File.WriteAllBytes("ImageToTiff_ByScanlines.tif", tiffBytes)

            Process.Start("ImageToBitonalTiff.tif")
        End Using 
    End Sub 

    Public Shared Function GetTiffImageBytes(ByVal img As Bitmap, ByVal byScanlines As Boolean) As Byte()
        Try 
            Dim raster As Byte() = GetImageRasterBytes(img)

            Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                Using tif As Tiff = Tiff.ClientOpen("InMemory", "w", ms, New TiffStream())
                    If tif Is Nothing Then 
                        Return Nothing 
                    End If

                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, img.Width)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, img.Height)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.COMPRESSION, Compression.CCITTFAX4)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK)

                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, img.Height)

                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION, img.HorizontalResolution)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION, img.VerticalResolution)

                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE, 0)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, 1)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.FILLORDER, FillOrder.MSB2LSB)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.ORIENTATION, Orientation.TOPLEFT)

                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.T6OPTIONS, 0)
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.RESOLUTIONUNIT, ResUnit.INCH)

                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.PLANARCONFIG, PlanarConfig.CONTIG)

                    Dim tiffStride As Integer = tif.ScanlineSize()
                    Dim stride As Integer = raster.Length / img.Height

                    If byScanlines Then 
                        ' raster stride MAY be bigger than TIFF stride (due to padding in raster raster) 
                        Dim i As Integer = 0, offset As Integer = 0 
                        While i < img.Height
                            Dim res As Boolean = tif.WriteScanline(raster, offset, i, 0)
                            If Not res Then 
                                Return Nothing 
                            End If

                            offset += stride
                            i += 1 
                        End While 
                    Else 
                        If tiffStride < stride Then 
                            ' raster stride is bigger than TIFF stride 
                            ' this is due to padding in raster bits 
                            ' we need to create correct TIFF strip and write it into TIFF 

                            Dim stripBits As Byte() = New Byte(tiffStride * img.Height - 1) {}
                            Dim i As Integer = 0, rasterPos As Integer = 0, stripPos As Integer = 0 
                            While i < img.Height
                                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(raster, rasterPos, stripBits, stripPos, tiffStride)
                                rasterPos += stride
                                stripPos += tiffStride
                                i += 1 
                            End While 

                            ' Write the information to the file 
                            Dim n As Integer = tif.WriteEncodedStrip(0, stripBits, stripBits.Length)
                            If n <= 0 Then 
                                Return Nothing 
                            End If 
                        Else 
                            ' Write the information to the file 
                            Dim n As Integer = tif.WriteEncodedStrip(0, raster, raster.Length)
                            If n <= 0 Then 
                                Return Nothing 
                            End If 
                        End If 
                    End If 
                End Using 

                Return ms.GetBuffer()
            End Using 
        Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
            Return Nothing 
        End Try 
    End Function 

    Public Shared Function GetImageRasterBytes(ByVal img As Bitmap) As Byte()
        ' Specify full image 
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height)

        Dim bmp As Bitmap = img
        Dim bits As Byte() = Nothing 

        Try 
            ' Lock the managed memory 
            If img.PixelFormat <> PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed Then
                bmp = convertToBitonal(img)
            End If 

            Dim bmpdata As BitmapData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)

            ' Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            bits = New Byte(bmpdata.Stride * bmpdata.Height - 1) {}

            ' Copy the sample values into the array.
            Marshal.Copy(bmpdata.Scan0, bits, 0, bits.Length)

            ' Release managed memory
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata)
        Finally 
            If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(bmp, img) Then
                bmp.Dispose()
            End If 
        End Try 

        Return bits
    End Function 

    Private Shared Function convertToBitonal(ByVal original As Bitmap) As Bitmap
        Dim sourceStride As Integer 
        Dim sourceBuffer As Byte() = extractBytes(original, sourceStride)

        ' Create destination bitmap 
        Dim destination As New Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)

        destination.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution)

        ' Lock destination bitmap in memory 
        Dim destinationData As BitmapData = destination.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height), ImageLockMode.[WriteOnly], PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)

        ' Create buffer for destination bitmap bits 
        Dim imageSize As Integer = destinationData.Stride * destinationData.Height
        Dim destinationBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(imageSize - 1) {}

        Dim sourceIndex As Integer = 0 
        Dim destinationIndex As Integer = 0 
        Dim pixelTotal As Integer = 0 
        Dim destinationValue As Byte = 0 
        Dim pixelValue As Integer = 128 
        Dim height As Integer = destination.Height
        Dim width As Integer = destination.Width
        Dim threshold As Integer = 500 

        For y As Integer = 0 To height - 1
            sourceIndex = y * sourceStride
            destinationIndex = y * destinationData.Stride
            destinationValue = 0
            pixelValue = 128 

            For x As Integer = 0 To width - 1 
                ' Compute pixel brightness (i.e. total of Red, Green, and Blue values)
                pixelTotal = CType(sourceBuffer(sourceIndex + 1), Integer) + CType(sourceBuffer(sourceIndex + 2), Integer) + CType(sourceBuffer(sourceIndex + 3), Integer)

                If pixelTotal > threshold Then
                    destinationValue += CByte(pixelValue)
                End If 

                If pixelValue = 1 Then
                    destinationBuffer(destinationIndex) = destinationValue
                    destinationIndex += 1
                    destinationValue = 0
                    pixelValue = 128 
                Else
                    pixelValue >>= 1 
                End If

                sourceIndex += 4 
            Next 

            If pixelValue <> 128 Then
                destinationBuffer(destinationIndex) = destinationValue
            End If 
        Next

        Marshal.Copy(destinationBuffer, 0, destinationData.Scan0, imageSize)
        destination.UnlockBits(destinationData)
        Return destination
    End Function 

    Private Shared Function extractBytes(ByVal original As Bitmap, ByRef stride As Integer) As Byte()
        Dim source As Bitmap = Nothing 

        Try 
            ' If original bitmap is not already in 32 BPP, ARGB format, then convert 
            If original.PixelFormat <> PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb Then
                source = New Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                source.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution)
                Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(source)
                    g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0)
                End Using 
            Else
                source = original
            End If 

            ' Lock source bitmap in memory 
            Dim sourceData As BitmapData = source.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.[ReadOnly], PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

            ' Copy image data to binary array 
            Dim imageSize As Integer = sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height
            Dim sourceBuffer As Byte() = New Byte(imageSize - 1) {}
            Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, sourceBuffer, 0, imageSize)

            ' Unlock source bitmap
            source.UnlockBits(sourceData)

            stride = sourceData.Stride
            Return sourceBuffer
        Finally 
            If Not Object.ReferenceEquals(source, original) Then
                source.Dispose()
            End If 
        End Try 

    End Function 
End Class 
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tweak threshold value. The value is used to decide what pixels will become white and what will remain black.

```
 Dim threshold As Integer = 500
```

Comment: boootiful, ty sir :)